# CSS/SASS select first occurence of an indirect child

Tags: css, sass

I want to select the first occurence of an element that is an indirect child of `<main/>`. I don't mind using SASS/SCSS syntax in order to achieve that if that's the only way currently :

```
<style>
  main header:first-of-type {
    color: red;
  }
</style>
<main>
  <div>
     <header>I'm red</header>
     <header>I'm black</header>
     <div>
       <header>I'm black</header>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div>
     <header>I'm black</header>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: What exactly is an "indirect child"? What would the "indirect child" in your example be?

Comment: Did you try `main div > header:first-of-type`? This should select the first header element inside a div inside main.

Comment: What you're describing is just the issue with `:first-of-type` ... it looks at the first of type within the parent, which in this case would include two results.  The only way I can see to do this would be to have some kind of marker (class-based) that's put in place via JavaScript (or some framework) that would ensure only one result.

Comment: Apologies - see my updated OP. The first occurence of the element I'm looking for will have nothing distinct about it (no specific class etc..). By first indirect child I mean that it is not a direct child of `<main/>` and that it is the nearest to `<main/>` of its type inside the tree of indirect children.

Comment: SASS is **never** the only way.  Whatever SASS can do, plain old CSS can do (since SASS is just compiled into plain old CSS).

Comment: What's the actual logic that defines "nearest"?  e.g., if the first two `main > div > header` tags were removed, which of the remaining two would be "nearest"?

Answer (score -1):

Use selector as `main > * header:first-of-type`

```css
main > * header:first-of-type {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div>
     <header>I'm red</header>
     <header>I'm black</header>
  </div>
  <header>I'm black</header>
</main>
```

Comment: You answer worked for a specific tree of elements. See my updated tree. I want it to work for any tree structure.

Comment: i think you dont have a choice other than using jquery to toggle some class based on the selector with `first()` element